# Calculate Number of Working Days without Holidays & Weekends

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

How can I calculate the number of working days between two dates without counting Saturdays, Sundays and holidays.

I have a table with the following fields:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGl6u.png)

I have the following table and what I want is that in the column called expr1 calculate the difference of working days.

Enter the code into Visual Basic, and call workingdays to the module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YnGI.png)

Replace the variables with the names of each column.

```
Function WorkingDays(ByVal FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA As Date, ByVal FECHA_IMPRESIÓN As Date) As Long
    While FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA <= FECHA_IMPRESIÓN
        Select Case True
            Case Weekday(FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA, vbMonday) > 5
            Case DCount("*", "Holidays", "Holiday = #" & Format(fromDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#") > 0
            Case Else: WorkingDays = WorkingDays + 1
        End Select
        FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA = FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

Then they tell me that in the query with the generator call the function Workingdays, but it does not give me a result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D24Mr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElvCn.png)

I accept and run the query but I get an error.

Comment: Save holidays in a separate table, enter those days manually, that will be mach easier than calculate on the fly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd327646(v=office.12). Not based on your code but does exactly what you're looking for. Tested in Access 2013 and works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony suggests in the comments, you will first need to construct a table containing dates of holidays, as these can vary from year-to-year.

Then, rather than using functions such as `DateDiff`, the easiest method is probably to incrementally count the number of days between the two dates, without incrementing the counter should the date be a Saturday or Sunday, or a member of your holidays table, e.g.:

```vb
Function WorkingDays(ByVal fromDate As Date, ByVal toDate As Date) As Long
    While fromDate <= toDate
        Select Case True
            Case Weekday(fromDate, vbMonday) > 5
            Case DCount("*", "Holidays", "Holiday = #" & Format(fromDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#") > 0
            Case Else: WorkingDays = WorkingDays + 1
        End Select
        fromDate = fromDate + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

The above assumes that you have a table called `Holidays` containing a field called `Holiday` with all of the holiday dates to be excluded.

The above function counts the number of working days inclusive of the two supplied dates.

For example, assuming that your `Holidays` table contains the following dates:

[image: Holidays]

Then the function would return the following:

```vb
?WorkingDays(#2018-12-24#, #2019-01-04#)
 7
```

To use the code, open the VBA IDE (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), insert a new Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>) and then paste the code into the module and save the module.

You can then call the function from anywhere where the Expression Builder is available.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I have a question: Where I put this code. I have a  two columns and I want a third one called validation to show me the working day.

Comment: How can I put the imagen the acces? for you can see

Comment: @LinaMarcelaHernándezDiaz I have updated my answer with more information about how the code can be used. Unfortunately your question has been marked as a duplicate and so you are limited in what you can do to change it.

Comment: Lee Mac, I added the example in the description of what I did but it does not run.

Comment: @LinaMarcelaHernándezDiaz The example included in my answer was run from within the VBA IDE Immediate Window, which you can access by pressing Ctrl+G whilst in the VBA IDE. To display a result in a textbox, for example, you might set the **Control Source** to `=WorkingDays([YourDateField1], [YourDateField2])`

Comment: Now is runing perfect but not discount the holidays day, I don't know  why.    Maybe is this line: Case DCount("*", "Holidays", "Holiday = #" & Format(fromDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#") > 0                                                            Can you explain me this staments. 
what does this ?. I change the  "mm/dd/yyyy" for  "dd/mm/yyyy"  because all my data are in this format.

Comment: @LinaMarcelaHernándezDiaz Assuming you have created the table per my example, do **not** change the date format in my code - this is the date format expected by SQL, not the format of your dates.

Comment: Lee Mac I want to give you a good califications. Thanks  alots

Comment: Thank you @LinaMarcelaHernándezDiaz Please mark my answer as the solution (if possible for a duplicate question) and upvote if appropriate.