# Calculate actual working days for each month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to calculate a factor for each employee and month. The factor depends on the actual working days.

For example to calculate it for April (4/1/2019 to 4/30/2019) one employee is on vacation from 4/8/2019 to 4/12/2019 and he will leave the company on the 4/26/2019.

April has 30 days and the employee has 5 days off and 4 days without contract (so hasn't the possibility to work for 9 days). In this case the factor would be 0.7 = (1/30)*(30-9).

How is it possible to count the clashing days for each month? It is also possible that an employee is on vacation from 3/25/2019 to 4/5/2019 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Number of Working Days without Holidays & Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400726/calculate-number-of-working-days-without-holidays-weekends)

Comment: For a start, you would have to define _clashing days_. In your example, we only have the count of days of April and the count of days not working. Nothing seems to "clash".